# Delete selected rows from an array

Tags: reactjs

here I want to clear those rows by pressing and selecting the DeleteRow button, the problem is that if I select rows from the top of the list, they will be removed without problems, but if the rows are from Selection down to top, selected rows cannot be deleted.

```
handleMultipleDelete = () =>{
        const arr=this.state.selectRowList;
        const product = this.state.productList;

        for (let i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i-- ){
           product.splice(arr[i], 1);
        }
          this.setState({
              productList: product,
              selectRowList: [],
          });
    }
```

My code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-inwdg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to sort the arr before deleting as they are the indexes of an array.

Here is the updated function

```
handleMultipleDelete = () => {
    const arr = this.state.selectRowList;
    const product = this.state.productList;
    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      product.splice(arr[i], 1);
    }
    this.setState({
      productList: product,
      selectRowList: []
    });
  };
```

Here is the [updated fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3e431).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this via `Array#filter()` as shown by the following:

```js
handleMultipleDelete = () => {

  const { selectRowList, productList } = this.state;
 
  // Filter product array ..
  const newProduct = productList.filter((product, index) => {
  
    // ..where product's index does not exist in selectRowList
    return selectRowList.some(select => index === select) === false
  });

  this.setState({
    productList: newProduct,
    selectRowList: [],
  });
}
```

By filtering the `product` array (rather than removing items per iteration of `arr` via `Array#splice`), this ensures that the original product indicies remain intact and consistent with the indicies in the `selectRowList` array during the filtering (ie removing unwanted items) stage.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your code, you've used the splice method. The splice method in fact affects the original array you are dealing with. So I would not recommend that.

Instead what you can do is, use the filter method of Array.

Something like this:

```
handleMultipleDelete = () => {
    const arr = this.state.selectRowList;
    const product = this.state.productList;

    const newProductArr = product.filter((product, index) => {
      return !arr.includes(index);
    });

    this.setState({
      productList: newProductArr,
      selectRowList: []
    });
  };
```

Hope it helps :)